# What code cost more at performance level

Tags: php, performance, oop, php-7

Every body knows that today technology is low cost and many of us don't really care about it. So, take a look to this codes:

Approach #1

```
$Obj = new Obj();

if (!empty($val1)) {
    $Obj->setVal1($val1);
}

if (!empty($val2)) {
    $Obj->setVal2($val2);
}

if (!empty($val3)) {
    $Obj->setVal3($val3);
}

if (!empty($valN)) {
    $Obj->setValN($valN);
}
```

Approach #2

```
if (!empty($var1) && !empty($var2) && !empty($var3) && !empty($varN)) {
    $Obj = new Obj();

    if (!empty($val1)) {
        $Obj->setVal1($val1);
    }

    if (!empty($val2)) {
        $Obj->setVal2($val2);
    }

    if (!empty($val3)) {
        $Obj->setVal3($val3);
    }

    if (!empty($valN)) {
        $Obj->setValN($valN);
    }
}
```

In the first example we're creating and object and leave around if none of the values exists, in the second one we are checking first if the values exists and aren't empty and then create the object and set the values. From your perspective which one would be the best solution in performance levels? Which one would you write on your codes?

**Note:** N is not infinite

Comment: Why don't you do a performance analysis and see for yourself?

Comment: They are not functionally equivalent.  And this is such a micro optimization I am not sure I worry about it.

Comment: In general both are pretty different. First approach is OR (there is no dependency between each `$val`, second is AND (all `$val` must not be empty).

Comment: Enable xdebug extension and do some profiling. Kcachegrind is a good tool.

Comment: You're doing more things in #2. 2 is more expensive.

Comment: Second approach is testing ALL 4 variables for `!empty` twice. Why would you do that if you are trying to _optimize_??

Comment: These kinds of "performance" improvements are just a waste of developer's life, nothing else. You shouldn't waste your time on this, the gain is questionable, and if it even exists - it's so minimal that it's not worth spending more text on it.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all for your time and answers I get it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is depend on what you want,
the first code will set value if it's not empty even tho' another value might be empty,

but the second code would check all of the value first, so if one of the value is empty, it will never create the Obj.

that is a clear choice,
if you think all value is important and necessary, then go with the second code, if it's fine to leave another value empty and want to update any value that is not empty there's no point on using the second code

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's *not* operations like `empty()` or `isset()` that wastes time. Instead higher memory usage and memory leakage tends to lead to more GC operations, `new()` performs initialization that takes time, I/O operations causes delay, and *that* is where you should do your improvement.

It can be very very complex if you want to discuss the time usage in detail: during compilation, runtime, whether the code will run at all etc.